# Javascript runs loop too much

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mind that I just started with JS.

I am writing a simple application in which a user needs to translate a word in English to a word in French. What I want to do is to show the English word in a div. The user then enters the French word in an input which is processed when the `enter` key is pressed.

I have two pages, Test2 contains an English and French word like below.

`yes,oui`

The other page contains all the JS and HTML. The problem I am encountering is that after the user has filled in one word (and this word is either correct or incorrect), the script should automatically move on to the next word (i.e. `no,non`). I tried to do this by making a function and calling this function inside this same function. For some reason this goes wrong after filling in the first word (the user is then asked multiple words at once). Does anyone have any idea to solve or work around this problem?

```
<script>
function getword(){
    var arr;
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", async: false, url: 'Test2', success: function(data) { 
        arr = data.split (",");
    }});
    return {or: arr[0], tr: arr[1]};
}
function process(or, tr){
    if(tr == $("#translation").val()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    go();
    function go(){
    var data = getword();
    var or = data.or;
    var tr = data.tr;
    alert("Translate to French: " + or);
    $("#translation").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            if(process(or, tr)){
                alert('good');
                go();
            }else{
                alert('bad');
                go();
            }
        }
    });
    }
}); 

</script>
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Antwoord" id="translation"/>
```

Comment: Where is the loop?

Comment: @vlaz I did not know what this would be called. But the 'loop' would be function go which is called inside the same function. I hoped this would result the application go move on to the next word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not reassign the key event handler on each run on of `go`. These are cumulative and so you will get a load of triggers of that key event handler after a while. So move that out of the `go` function, and declare your variables one level up, so they stay in scope for the event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var or, tr; // <!-- define here
    go();
    function go(){
        var data = getword();
        or = data.or;
        tr = data.tr;
        alert("Translate to French: " + or);
    }

    $("#translation").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            if(process(or, tr)){
                alert('good');
                go();
            }else{
                alert('bad');
                go();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

NB: it is not considered good practice to interact with the user via `alert`. Consider putting a text on the page, for instance in a `div` element.

Comment: This seems to be working! I used the alert more for debugging purposes and was not planning to use it in the actual application. Could you explain why you want to define the or and tr variables before the go function?

Comment: This is because the `or`and `tr` variables are referenced both in the `go` function and in the key event handler. To make sure they are available to both these functions, you cannot declare them inside of one of them, so that is why you need to declare them at a higher level, i.e. in the function that contains both other functions.